# Minecraft won't allow me to upload my own skin, can someone please help?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

I have tried multiple times to upload a skin that has been saved to my camera roll on my iPad. It is coming up with this message (pic attached). I've asked people in my family and none of them know what has happened.
If you guys could help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a stable internet connection? Also, are the photos available locally on your phone or only on the cloud>

Comment: For all I know it's a stable internet connection, and I'm not totally sure about that

Comment: You're saying that you can't upload to minecraft but the error you're posting is downloading from icloud. This doesn't seem related to minecraft or gaming at all

Answer (score 0):

That's what happened to mine, all you have to do is get the skin again, then it will work as long as it is the latest photo you have done, which it will be.